# Running "bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy" gives "Permission denied"

Tags: magento2, css, installation, cli, command

When running:

> **root@ubuntu:/var/www/Magento2#** bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

I got

> **-bash: bin/magento: Permission denied**

please note that I'm running the command using root user

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l bin/magento`?

Comment: Please provide `execute` permission to for it even for `ROOT` user. `chmod -x bin/magento`

Comment: use like php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

The php need to be added before bin/magento

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 0):

Use word php before the command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Refer : [Devdocs : static contents](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments:

Check the permission of the file like so:

`ls -lah bin/magento`

You will see that the execute permissions are missing. Therefore add the execute permissions like so:

`chmod +x bin/magento`

If you don't want to allow execution for that script, you can run the script with your local php installation like so:

`php bin/magento ...`

**Nevertheless you should not run any command as root.**

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix permissions, you can run all of these commands, or at least the last two since it is not mentioned that you've configured permissions on app/:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```